# Why can't one omit white space after primitive data types?

Tags: compiler-construction, whitespace

Why don't compilers let me use `intmain` instead of `int main`? Don't compilers discard white spaces at compile time?

Comment: which programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Popular ones like C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tokenizers discard white space in the sense that they don't generate a token for it. But that doesn't mean that white space has no effect at all: it still forces one token to end and the next to begin.

One way to think of it is that a tokenizer has three jobs:

1. Split the input text into lexemes (substrings).
2. Classify each lexeme into a category like "identifier" or "white space".
3. Generate a stream of token values that contain the value and the classification of each lexeme.

The way that jobs 1 and 2 work is that we define rules for each type of token. The tokenizer then takes the rule which matches the longest prefix of the current input. It then generates the lexeme and classifies it based on which rule was used to match it.

So what we mean when we say that tokenizers "ignore" white space is that job 3 doesn't generate a token for lexemes that have been classified as white space. This does not in any way affect job 1.

To illustrate this, the three jobs for the input `int main()` would look as follows:

1. `"int", " ", "main", "(", ")"`
2. `KEYWORD_INT, SPACE, IDENTIFIER, OPEN_PAR, CLOSING_PAR`
3. `KEYWORD_INT, IDENTIFIER("main"), OPEN_PAR, CLOSING_PAR`

And for `intmain()` it would look like this:

1. `"intmain", "(", ")"`
2. `IDENTIFIER, OPEN_PAR, CLOSING_PAR`
3. `IDENTIFIER("main"), OPEN_PAR, CLOSING_PAR`

The reason that we get `intmain` and not `int, main` is that the identifier rule still keeps matching after the `t`.

In a comment on another answer you asked, why `int` doesn't get priority. That'd mean that we change the logic of job 1, so that it doesn't take the rule with the longest match, but rather always prefers the "keyword int" rule over the "identifier" rule. This would make it impossible to ever have an identifier that starts with "int" (because that would always be classified as the keyword `int`), so that'd be a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

How is the compiler supposed to know that you meant for `intmain` to mean `int main`? Why not `in tmain` or `intma in`? Or indeed just `intmain`? It can't read your mind.

So, no, they don't discard whitespaces, because they can't.

Comment: Can't they give priority to `int`?

Comment: @Dante: Why would they do that? Just type a space like everyone else.

Comment: @Dante They could, but then you wouldn't ever be able to have a variable whose name starts with `int` (as well as other keywords, assuming you want them treated the same way), which seems a rather bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example:

```
class in{};
in tmain() {return in();}
```

How can compiler make a difference between this declaration and `intmain` from your example?
So compilers discard space symbols (tabs, whitespaces, carriage returns) between distinguishable tokens only.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers discard *superfluous* whitespace.

Word/symbol breaks are still required, otherwise, there would be no way to know if you meant a variable named `intmain` or were starting a function `int main...`.

Superfluous whitespace is mostly multiple whitespace, and whitespace between successive symbols.